# Percentile rank of a cell that isn't in an array - EXCEL

Tags: arrays, excel, rank

I have an array of numbers and would like to see what percentile another cell would be in if it was included in that array. I can't directly do the RANK function because the cell I'm testing isn't in the array. There's a number of cells I'm looking to find the percentile rank for as well.

Perhaps there's a way to select an array AND a separate cell to be included in the Rank function?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a union of ranges in the second argument of the RANK function, for example:

```
 =RANK(B1,(A1:A4,B1),1)
```

If numbers are on a different sheet another option is:

```
 =COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A4,"<"&B1)+1
```

Comment: That works as long as half the of the ranges are from another sheet. But as long as all the values are on the same sheet, it works perfectly.

Comment: I think you could use the `COUNTIF()` function if the range is on a different sheet as in the updated response